# local GAE datastore does not keep data after computer shuts down

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

On my local machine (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/`), I have entered data into my GAE datastore for some entity called `Article`. After turning off my computer and then restarting next day, I find the datastore empty: no entity. Is there a way to prevent this in the future?

How do I make a copy of the data in my local datastore? Also, will I be able to upload said data later into both localhost and production?

My model is `ndb`.

I am using Max OS X and Python 2.7, if theses matter.

Comment: I am using `GoogleAppEngineLauncher` to launch my apps, not the terminal.

Comment: I have the same issue. However, I am using Linux. The default datastore path is located in the /tmp directory, which might be the reason the datastore is deleted after each shut-down. And changing the `--datastore-path` works for me.

Answer (score 8):

I have experienced the same problem. Declaring the datastore path when running dev_appserver.py should fix it. These are the arguments I use when starting the dev_appserver

```
python dev_appserver.py --high_replication --use_sqlite --datastore_path=myapp.datastore --blobstore_path=myapp_blobs
```

This will use sqlite and save the data in the file myapp.datastore. If you want to save it in a different directory, use --datastore_path=/path/to/myapp/myapp.datastore

I also use --blobstore_path to save my blobs in a specific directory. I have found that it is more reliable to declare which directory to save my blobs. Again, that is --blobstore_path=/path/to/myapp/blobs or whatever you would like.

Since declaring blob and datastore paths, I haven't lost any data locally. More info can be found in the App Engine documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_the_Datastore

Answer (score 1):

Data in the local datastore is preserved unless you start it with the -c flag to clear it, at least on the PC. You therefore probably have a different issue with temp files or permissions or something.

The local data is stored using a different method to the actual production servers, so not sure if you can make a direct backup as such. If you want to upload data to both the local and deployed servers you can use the Upload tool suite:  [uploading data](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata)

> The bulk loader tool can upload and download data to and from your application's datastore. With just a little bit of setup, you can upload new datastore entities from CSV and XML files, and download entity data into CSV, XML, and text files. Most spreadsheet applications can export CSV files, making it easy for non-developers and other applications to produce data that can be imported into your app. You can customize the upload and download logic to use different kinds of files, or do other data processing.

So you can 'backup' by downloading the data to a file.

To load/pull data into the local development server just give it the local URL.

Comment: So far I have only been using GAE on local server. I don't have any credentials setup. When I try to install the remote_api through `appcfg.py update <app-directory>`, I am asked for email. Must I first setup credentials to download the api? I was hoping to relegate that to when I need to go to production.

Comment: I've had credentials all along, so I've no idea, it was so long ago.

Comment: You must set up an account before you upload your app to the production servers.

Answer (score 1):

The datastore typically saves to disk when you shut down.  If you turned off your computer without shutting down the server, I could see this happening.